# Spark Coalesce error - no such method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, coalesce

i got this error. I'm not sure why this is the case because there is a coalesce method in org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD. 
Any ideas? 
Am I running a incompatible version of Spark and org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.coalesce$default$3(IZ)Lscala/math/Ordering;
```

Comment: which version of Spark are you building with ? Running with ? Which are you using in your IDE ?

Comment: Also which Scala version?

Answer (score 2):

It was because some part of your code or project dependencies called old version(spark version before 2.0.0) spark API 'coalesce' while in new version spark this API has been removed and replaced by 'repartition'.

To fix this problem, you could either downgrade your spark run environment to below version 2.0.0, or you can upgrade your SDK spark version to above 2.0.0 and upgrade project dependencies version to be compatible with spark 2.0.0 or above.

For more details please see this thread:
https://github.com/twitter/algebird/issues/549
https://github.com/EugenCepoi/algebird/commit/0dc7d314cba3be588897915c8dcfb14964933c31

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, this is a library compatibility issue. Everything works (no code change) after downgrading Spark alone.

Before:

- scala 2.11.8
- spark 2.0.1
- Java 1.8.0_92

After

- scala 2.11.8
- spark 1.6.2
- Java 1.8.0_92

OS: OSX 10.11.6